# How to handle a one line for loop without putting it in a List?

Tags: python

Maybe the question is a bit vague, but what I mean is this code:

```
'livestream' : [cow.legnames for cow in listofcows]
```

Now the problem is cow.legnames is also a list so I will get a list in a list when I try to return it with Json. How should I make it to return a single list.

This is the json that would be returned.

```
'livestream' : [['blue leg', 'red leg']]
```

I hope the code explains what my question is.

Comment: To be less vague you give an example about naming your cows' legs?

Comment: Your syntax `string_constant : list_comprehension` is peculiar; is this an item in a dict? For avoidance of doubt, it would be very helpful if you gave at least one syntactically correct statement, rather than a fragment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In addition to shahjapan's reduce you can use this syntax to flatten list.

```
[legname for cow in listofcows for legname in cow.legnames]
```

Comment: I didn't have time to test this answer out yet. But I'm guessing this is the right answer. Will accept your answer as soon as I try it out, but im quite busy right now. Thanks for your answer though. Appreciate it.

Comment: Works perfect. This was the way I wanted to do it. Didn't know I would be able to do 2 for loops in one line ;)

Answer (score 2):

The name `listofcows` implies there may be, possibly in a distant future, several cows. Flattening a list of list with more than one item would be simply wrong.

But if the name is misleading (and why a one-lement list anyway, for that matter?), you have several options to flatten it.

Nested list comprehension: `[legname for cow in listofcows cow.legnames for legname in cow.legnames]`

Getting the first item: `[your list comprehension][0]`

And very likely some useful thingy from the standard library I don't remember right now.

Comment: As to the "useful thingy", I think you're thinking of `sum(nested_list, [])`

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, you have something like this:

```
class Cow(object):
    def __init__(self, legnames):
        self.legnames = legnames

listofcows = [Cow(['Red Leg', 'Blue Leg']), 
              Cow(['Green Leg', 'Red Leg'])]
```

It's easiest extend a temporary list, like this:

```
legs = []

# As @delnan noted, its generally a bad idea to use a list
# comprehension to modify something else, so use a for loop
# instead.
for cow in listofcows:
    legs.extend(cow.legnames)


# Now use the temporary legs list...
print {'livestream':legs}
```

Comment: List comprehensions with side effects are bad enough, but a list comprehension solely for side effects is simply unpythonic and horrible. Use a for-loop.

Comment: @delnan - I agree, but I was trying to mirror what the OP was doing to make things clearer to him.

Comment: Edit and state that this is a bad idea and just an example, and I'll undownvote :)

Comment: Yea I will go with a 2 line for loop. Thought maybe there was a shortway by removing the list [] symbols but that didn't work either.

Comment: `for cow in listofcows: legs.extend(cow.legnames)` does work without linebreak after the colon.

Comment: Beware, StackOverflow seems to have changed its system rules recently and you can't undownvote after a certain amount of time.

Comment: @uosɐſ You can always change your downvote if the entry has since been edited.

Comment: And just in time, there comes the edit - undownvoted; it was a pleasure to deal with you, sir `:p`

Comment: Yea. I just made it the same way as you with the for loop. Seems it's better in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
'livestream' : [cow.legnames[0] for cow in listofcows]
```

Comment: No It seems the answer by Joe is the most suited as it's not so good to use the comprehension list here.

Answer (score 0):

you can try reduce,
`'livestream' : reduce(lambda a,b:a+b,[cow.legs for cow in listofcows])`

if you need unique legs use set

`'livestream' :list(set(reduce(lambda a,b:a+b,[cow.legs for cow in listofcows])))`

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `chain.from_itterable` from python itertools Consider the following example:

```
from itertools import chain

list(chain.from_iterable(cow.legnames for cow in listofcows))
```

See also [chain.from_iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) from the python documentation.